# Geometry Proof : How to prove that $BV$ and $CT$ are perpendicular

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle. We construct squares $ABST$ and $ACUV$ with centers $O_1$ and $O_2$, respectively, as shown. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $\overline{BC}$.

(a) Prove that $\overline{BV}$ and $\overline{CT}$ are equal in length and perpendicular.

(b) Prove that $\overline{O_1 M}$ and $\overline{O_2 M}$ are equal in length and perpendicular.

**Diagram**

[image: Enter image description[1]]

**My work so far**

[image: Enter image description[2]]

I am stuck on how to prove the lengths are perpendicular...

Answer (score 1):

For (a) :

Let $D$ be the intersection point of $BV$ with $CT$.

You already know that $\triangle{TAC}$ and $\triangle{BAV}$ are congruent, so we have $\angle{ATC}=\angle{ABV}$. So, the four points $A,T,D,B$ are concyclic from which we have $\angle{TDB}=\angle{TAB}=90^\circ$.

For (b) :

You already know that $MO_2$ is parallel to $BV$ and that $MO_1$ is parallel to $CT$. Therefore, 
$$\angle{O_1MO_2}=\angle{TDV}=90^\circ.$$